# PHP code in HTML mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am working on an application that is used for managing the groups of recipients and multiple contents to send

I want to use different html design so i saved it in a table with some PHP code in it.

But problem is this, I m not getting the PHP code executed when send mail using these HTML contents.

I m using PHPMailer for sending mails and saved HTML contents using addslashes and getting back with stripslashes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Saved HTML contents using addslashes and getting back with
> stripslashes.

That's bad. I don't know why you did, but if your intention was to escape queries, use [**mysql_real_escape_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or an analgoue function for your DB driver (or use parametrized queries).
If your intention was to, I don't know, sanitize html? well, that's useless. So no need to add slashes here for any reason.

> But problem is this, I m not getting the PHP code executed when send
> mail using these HTML contents.

Because your content is returned as a string, so PHP will read it as such, tags included.

<sub>A dirtiest solution, **AND HIGHLY DISCOURAGED**, is using [**eval()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to evaluate php code and have it executed. But this is very risky and can lead to serious security problems, so I'm not even going to show you some example :)</sub>

The **BEST SOLUTION** is to use some sort of templating system. I'm not suggesting using Smarty or another full-blown template engine, but you can roll-out a simple custom-code parser that can work along these lines:

You save your variables using a placeholder, like

```
{{variable_text}}  {{recipient}} {{address}}
```

or something like this. The you just replace what you need, so in your PHP script that reads this e-mail you can do like

```
$change = array('recipient' => 'John Smith',
                'address' => 'Unknown Avenue, 666',
                'variable_text' => 'We are glad to invite you to');

$text = '<p>To: {{recipient}}.</p>
         <p>Address: {{address}}.</p>
         Message: Dear{{recipient}}<br />{{variable_text}}';
foreach($change as $k => $v)
{
   $text = str_replace('{{'.$k.'}}', $v, $text);
}
```